# Sorting of objects in an array by integer property value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There is an array which looks like this:

```
[
  { 
    _id: 'xxnQt5X8pfbcJMn6i',
    order: 2
  },
  { 
    _id: 'X8pfbcJxxnQt5Mn6i',
    order: 1
  },
  { 
    _id: 'Qt5X8pfxxnbcJMn6i',
    order: 3
  }
]
```

Now I need to sort the objects of this array by the `order` value. I tried to do this:

```
array.sort((a, b) => {
  return (a.order > b.order)
    ? 1
    : (b.order > a.order)
      ? -1
      : 0
})
```

But first it looks to me a bit to complicated for just sorting by an integer value and second it gives me the error `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '1' of object '[object Array]'`

Comment: I believe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript might help

Comment: I came up from this post (linked by apomene and GetOff My Lawn), but I run into the error shown above.

Comment: the sort is working fine, what is the problem with it?

Comment: array.sort((a, b) => b.order- a.order).slice(...)

Comment: @NinaScholz I do get the error `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '1' of object '[object Array]'`

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @user3142695 There aren't any assignment statements in your question, so it's not clear how that error is occuring.

Comment: I can't see anything glaringly wrong with this code...

Comment: I tried your code and it works

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), no need for the further return conditions on the ternary operator, the array will implicitly be sorted by the first comparison:

```js
console.log([
  { 
    _id: 'xxnQt5X8pfbcJMn6i',
    order: 2
  },
  { 
    _id: 'X8pfbcJxxnQt5Mn6i',
    order: 1
  },
  { 
    _id: 'Qt5X8pfxxnbcJMn6i',
    order: 3
  }
].sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order))
```

I can't reproduce the error that you're getting using the example provided though.

Comment: this is wrong because you use only `true`/`false` and not the needed smaller than zero, uero or greater than zero values, by not using all possible return values. this could leave to wroing sorted results.

Comment: Changed to `a.order - b.order`.

Comment: that does not explain the error, because there is no error in the question.